# r plotly with an animation and a restyle button

Tags: r, animation, plotly, interactive

I'm putting together a `plotly` time series animation and want to colour-code the points by different variables in the data using `updatemenus`, following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63940025/menu-or-buttons-to-select-by-which-variable-style-the-plot-in-r-plotly). I'm running into a few problems:

In the non-animated version:

1. The legend doesn't show up
2. The colour-coding scheme is correct for `COL1`, but doesn't work at all for `COL3`.

For the animated version:

1. The legend shows up, but does not show the correct categories (1/2 for `COL1`, a/b for `COL3)
2. The colour-coding itself seems thoroughly broken - the points aren't colour-coded correctly, and clicks on the animation slider seem to change the colour of the points.

I tried handling this via updating the visibility of the traces, instead of recolouring them, but since the number of unique traces changes between frames (I don't have all groups in all dates), I can't figure out how to change the visibility with a dynamically changing number of traces.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Example data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(X = rnorm(20), Y=rnorm(20), Date = rep(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-10"), "1 day"), 2)) %>%
        mutate(Date = as.factor(Date),
                COL1 = sample(c("1","2"), n(), replace =  TRUE), 
                COL3 = sample(c("a","b"), n(), replace =  TRUE),
                Text = paste(COL1, COL3)) %>%
        arrange(Date)
```

Non-animated plot:

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = dat, x = ~X, y = ~Y, hovertext = ~Text, type="scatter",  mode="markers") %>% 
  layout(updatemenus=list(
      list(type = "buttons", y = 0.8,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle", args = list("marker.color",list(~COL1)),
               label = "COL1"),
          list(method = "restyle", args = list("marker.color",list(~COL3)),
               label = "COL3")))))
```

Animated plot:

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = dat, x = ~X, y = ~Y, frame = ~Date, hovertext = ~Text, frame = ~Date, type="scatter",  mode="markers") %>% 
  layout(updatemenus=list(
      list(type = "buttons", y = 0.8,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle", args = list("marker.color",list(~COL1)),
               label = "COL1"),
          list(method = "restyle", args = list("marker.color",list(~COL3)),
               label = "COL3")))))
```